# Python 2.7.6 String Literal error with Quotations in Quotations

Tags: python, string, syntax-error, literals, eol

In the function

```
print 'He said, "\"She\'s pretty"\'
```

I am getting an error that says "There's an error in your program: EOL while scanning string literal" How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

No need to escape the double quotes, but the big problem is the escape of the single quote at the end, when you *want* to end the string

```
print 'He said, "She\'s pretty"'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print 'He said, "She\'s pretty."'
```

In a single-quoted string, you should only escape *single* quotes that you *don't* want to be treated as the end of the string. The single quote at the end shouldn't be escaped, since it marks the end of the string.

(Also, I've ended the sentence with a period. You can take that out if you want.)